# Custom Keybord return title set IOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

I built a custom keyboard. But i faced a problem that return button title change. Suppose when i go to search bar from my keyboard then it should show "Go". And for default textfield it should show "return"For Searchbar it should show "search".

How can i get the keyboadType and how can i do that can anybody help me ? Though keyboadType return only bool value.

```
- (void)textDidChange:(id<UITextInput>)textInput {
 UIColor *textColor = nil;
    if (self.textDocumentProxy.keyboardAppearance == UIKeyboardAppearanceDark) {
        textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    } else {
        textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
      NSLog(@"Keyboard Type: %d", self.textDocumentProxy.keyboardType);
    NSLog(@"key: %d",  [textInput keyboardType]);
}
```

Here both return bool value 0 for All field such as web search,email,defaulttext field.

Answer (score 1):

There's a property

```
@property(nonatomic) UIReturnKeyType returnKeyType;
```

defined in the `UITextInputTraits` protocol.
So what you probably want to do is:

```
UITextField *myTextField; // your textfield..
myTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyGo;
```

For other possible values see `UIReturnKeyType`:

```
typedef enum {
    UIReturnKeyDefault,
    UIReturnKeyGo,
    UIReturnKeyGoogle,
    UIReturnKeyJoin,
    UIReturnKeyNext,
    UIReturnKeyRoute,
    UIReturnKeySearch,
    UIReturnKeySend,
    UIReturnKeyYahoo,
    UIReturnKeyDone,
    UIReturnKeyEmergencyCall,
} UIReturnKeyType;
```

This might helps :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard type and return key type are two different things.  Keyboard type is defined by UIKeyboardType:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIKeyboardType) {
    UIKeyboardTypeDefault,                // Default type for the current input method.
    UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable,           // Displays a keyboard which can enter ASCII characters, non-ASCII keyboards remain active
    UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation,  // Numbers and assorted punctuation.
    UIKeyboardTypeURL,                    // A type optimized for URL entry (shows . / .com prominently).
    UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad,              // A number pad (0-9). Suitable for PIN entry.
    UIKeyboardTypePhonePad,               // A phone pad (1-9, *, 0, #, with letters under the numbers).
    UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad,           // A type optimized for entering a person's name or phone number.
    UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress,           // A type optimized for multiple email address entry (shows space @ . prominently).
    UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(4_1),   // A number pad with a decimal point.
    UIKeyboardTypeTwitter NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0),      // A type optimized for twitter text entry (easy access to @ #)
    UIKeyboardTypeWebSearch NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0),    // A default keyboard type with URL-oriented addition (shows space . prominently).
    UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable, // Deprecated
};
```

Return key type is defined by UIReturnKeyType:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIReturnKeyType) {
    UIReturnKeyDefault,
    UIReturnKeyGo,
    UIReturnKeyGoogle,
    UIReturnKeyJoin,
    UIReturnKeyNext,
    UIReturnKeyRoute,
    UIReturnKeySearch,
    UIReturnKeySend,
    UIReturnKeyYahoo,
    UIReturnKeyDone,
    UIReturnKeyEmergencyCall,
};
```

You can use `textDocumentProxy.returnKeyType` to get the return key type and change return key accordingly.